# How can I allow an employee to edit only certain tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I edit my database in phpMyAdmin.
I can have only 1 account.
I have DB host, DB user, DB name and password (my hosting).
I need to allow the employee to edit only certain tables.
Are there such tools? php-scripts? other ways? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You have only one account for your whole db or one for you and one for your employees ?

Comment: @dima ,elabarate your question .plz .Tell us the exact context

Comment: You can write a script that interact only with that table, and give to the employee instead of real access to the database

Comment: It is possible to create MySql Users with Table Specific Privileges. To limit users access/actions per table. If you want these users to access the database they can use MySql client softwares to access the remote database.  When you create the user you need to set the host as % to allow remote login to your database

Comment: @denil as far as I read, the OP has only one account, and might have more than one employee. So the OP needs more than one physical persons to use the same mysql account, and to be restricted to different tables. Which means, the OP needs a layer before the mysql, to interact with the database

Comment: @RoyalBg assuming that he only has 1 user account then he will need to create a script that will handle roles,access to each employee he adds into the system. But as a web host provider I doubt that he's only limited to 1 database account

Comment: Eventually I wrote php-script. I thought there is a ready solution. I still believe that there is an easier way ("turnkey" solution) than writing own script. Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to grant PRIVILEGES to that user with only UPDATE permission

1. Go to your Console and login to MySql
2. Create user to whom you want to grant privileges in following way

   ```
   CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
   ```
3. Then give permission to specific table

   ```
   GRANT [UPDATE ] ON [database name].[table name] TO ‘[username]’@'localhost’;
   ```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I cannot create new users

Comment: Can you login to your database at least? so on that basis I can suggest you more solution

Comment: I use phpMyAdmin. It install in hosting

Comment: You can create user by phpMyAdmin as well but If it is a shared hosting then, its quite difficult. ask to your service provider if you can create multiple DB user. If YES then go to SQL in phpmyadmin and run above first query. you need to provide the username and password in in that. keep credentials noted somewhere and then put them in second query.

Comment: Does this forbids the employee from seeing the content of other tables too? Does update allows deletion ?

Answer (score 3):

My answer might not be right, but as far as I understand from the question:

The OP has only one mysql account, and needs this account, to be used by his employee/s for special tables. So, if the OP grant privilleges only to certain tables on this account, the permissions will be equal to everyone who uses the account.

In this case, I would suggest to make a simple database interacting interface, on the top of this account. This layer would have its own accounts, and depending on which account is logged in the application, the interface should show the tables you want.

For example, if there's a field for entering a table to perform select/update/whatever query, you should check
if (in_array($field, $allowedTables)) in order to grant the user to perform the query.

Comment: This is really the only correct answer here. Unfortunately, it requires a bit of extra work to code up the application that handles the interfacing with the database. I suppose the true best answer is to switch to a host that allows you to have more than one database user, but you probably shouldn't really be giving your employees their own MySQL account and access through phpMyAdmin anyway, bringing us back to the need to code your own application to give them access to what they need and lock them out from what they don't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `view`.Create views for the certain tables and forbide the select privileges for the employee。